# How to uninstall .NET CF 3.5 if remove from control panel failed?

Tags: .net-framework, windows-ce

I was working on a program and while I am deploying the power went out. When the power back on I can't run/debug my .NET 3.5 program on target Windows CE anymore. I am trying to remove .NET CF 3.5 from control panel but it failed and complains some files are locked or read only.

Is there any other or manual way I can uninstall .NET CF 3.5 from my Windows CE?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Here is the .Net cleanup tool, but I am not sure it will run on CE, so I am not posting it as an anwser. If it works, post back. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/05/30/611355.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution. It's actually very easy.

Use Regedit open HKLM/Software/Microsoft/.NETCompactFramework, delete the key named 3.5.xxxx.xx  (x being any digit)

Run .NET 3.5 deploy CAB on windows ce. .NET3.5 will install like it was never installed before.